# Count number of services defined in docker-compose.yml file

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose, sh

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file. After starting docker services using `docker-compose -f {docker-compose.yml path} up -d`, I want to check if all the services defined in `docker-compose.yml` are running.

I can get a count of all running services using `docker ps | wc -l`. How can I get the count of all services defined in `docker-compose.yml`?

If I have the count of all services defined in `docker-compose.yml`, I can compare this number with the number of services running to check if all services are running.

Comment: `check if all services are running.` This is XY question. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68526134/9072753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Count lines from `--services` output:

```
docker-compose ps --services | wc -l
```