# How to write a Dockerfile to let docker build failed if the built container fails to run?

Tags: node.js, docker, continuous-integration, continuous-delivery

I have a nodejs webapp run in docker, the Dockerfile is just the usual stuff as in [Dockerizing a Node.js web app](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/). But I hope to do one thing **differently**: if the docker container fails to run, e.g. incorrect node_modules I would like `docker build` fails.

If I just add `RUN npm run start` in Dockerfile and it fails to run, `docker build` indeed fails. But if `npm run start` succeeds, docker build won't exit then.

My goal is that if `docker run` fails, I hope `docker build` fails first. Currently I can't find a way to do that, so I have to write a script to first `docker build` then `docker run` and check its result.

--- update ---

I know normally it is in build/test/release order and testing comes after the build. But I am trying to improving our CI process and after build I hope to do a quick test to make sure the container can start correctly. If that needs a manual check it is quite unproductive. So I think why not do a one step further? If container can not start why not just fails the build?

--- update 2 ---

I felt rather uncomfortable with the answer I got. The main reason is that I felt that solution was dirty. I raised another question about it at SE's softwareengineering website [Improve CI process by testing against docker image and fail docker build if test fails](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/437568/improve-ci-process-by-testing-against-docker-image-and-fail-docker-build-if-test) and now I fully agree that what I proposed was not a good idea. Also github action is a good solution to reduce failed docker images.

Comment: What you're asking is literally impossible. There are many reasons docker run could fail and you can't test them during a build, and anyway, it's the wrong thing to do. Testing comes after the build step, not during it. We build, test, release, and deploy, in that order.

Comment: I am trying to improving our CI process and I know normally it is in build/test/release order. But after build I hope to do quick test automatically to make sure the container can start correctly. If that needs a manual check it is quite unproductive. Then I think why not do a one step further?

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Now I agree what I asked was a bad idea, please check my update.

Answer (score 1):

I would approach it in this way:

First find out how long does `npm run start` takes for you. In normal cases it won't take more than 15-20 seconds but let's say, it takes 60 seconds for your app to successfully start. Now I would keep a conditional statement in the server.js or the main entrypoint of your app like:

```
if (process.argv[2] === 'BUILD') { // Call only when docker build is ran
    setTimeout(() => process.exit(0), 60000) // This would wait for 60 seconds and if the app is still running it will terminate it.
}
```

You just need to ensure that you call `RUN npm run start -- --BUILD` while running the server during docker build as the `-- --BUILD` would pass a runtime argument to your server to ensure that it was called during the build process. For normal docker run entrypoint you can just call `npm run start` and it should work fine.

Comment: Thanks, that is one way to do it. Give me a couple of days to see if there is other ways before I may accept your answer.

Comment: One of concerns I have is that I have not seen many people do that.

Comment: Hi I finally gave up your suggested solution. Take a look at my update if you still are interested in it.