# Filter Docker volumes using not equal !=

Tags: docker, docker-volume

It's pretty straight forward to filter out docker volumes using:
`docker volume ls --filter "label=something"`

However I want to run something like:
`docker volume ls --filter "label!=something"'`

Some old StackOverflow answers said it's possible but I can't find it anywhere in the Docker docs.
I also get this error when I try running the command:

`Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'label!'`

Does anyone know a way to do it without using grep and piping?

Comment: The documentation is very clear. It doesn't mention a negation operator, so I'd say that there isn't one. Presumably the devs decided that there was no need to duplicate functionality which is available very simply in the shell.

Answer (score 1):

The official documentation for [docker volume ls](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/) doesn't mention a way to do this. Hence we can safely assume that there is no direct way to do what you have asked.

Also suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31959682/737440