# Docker prune all volumes except for a few

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to prune all volumes except for one or two. I'm trying to use the `docker volume prune` command with the [`--filter`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_ls/#-filtering---filter) option but I'm getting an error:

```
$ docker volume prune --filter 'name!=volume1' --force
Error response from daemon: Invalid filter 'name!'
```

Looks like it's complaining about the "not equals" syntax. How can I get this to work?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60089935/filter-docker-volumes-using-not-equal

Comment: It's not "related", its a duplicate